# Populate form without model in laravel

Tags: laravel, binding, routes

My application is made in laravel for a competition admin.

I have 'create' and 'edit' forms on Teams and Players. One team has multiple players.

I would like to link from the Team page to the 'create player' page. The Create Player page does not use a model (doesn't bind). How can I still prefill the select box with the team from the team page? Can I bind without saving a record in the database?

What should my routes be like?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the team ID in the URL?

```
/players/create?team={teamId}
```

PlayersController@create method:

```
$teams = Team::all();

return view('players.create', compact('teams'));
```

`players.create` view:

```
<select name="team">
@foreach ($teams as $team) {
    <option value="{{ $team->id }}"{{ $request->has('team') && $request->query('team') === $team->id ? ' selected' : '' }}>{{ $team->name }}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a route for example

```
// teamId is optional
Route::get('player/create/{teamId?}', ['as' => 'player_create', function ($teamId = null) {

    // You can of course better do this logic in a controller!
    // just an example :)

    // check if $teamId is null here for example

    // Or whatever logic you want to grab a team by
    $team = Team::find($teamId);        
    $teams = Team::all();        

    // Again.. or whatever way you want to pass your data!
    return view('player.create', ['teamName' => $team->name, 'teams' => $teams, 'whatever' => 'elseyouneed']);

}]);
```

And in the form of your view:

```
{!! Form::select('team', $teams, $teamName) !!}
```

### Edit

since html isn't part of the core anymore, you can't use that out of the box so I suppose Chris' approach is better. You could however install a [package](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.2/html) for it.